# How to display header and footer all pages of the pdf while converting jinja template to pdf using pdfkit

Tags: jinja2, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm new to Python and Jinja Templates. I have a header and body on a jinja template. I used pdfkit.from_string(html_content, False, config='wkhtmltopdf.exe path') to convert this template to PDF format. The PDF conversion was completed, however header displayed only on the first page of the pdf. I want to display the header every pages of the PDF. Give me the solution, please.

Code details mentioned blow

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
import pandas as pd
import pdfkit 

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():

html_content = '''
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>

                <head>
                    <title>Body</title>
                    <style>
                        .header{
                        position: running(header)
                        background-color: #f2f2f2;
                        padding:10px;
                        text-align:center;
                    }
                    @page {
                        @top-center {
                            content: element(header)
                        }
                    }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class='header'><h1>Header content</h1></div>
                                    
                    <table class='table'>
                        <tr class='table__header'>
                            <th style='background-color: #2F75B5;'>Name</th>
                            <th style='background-color: #2F75B5;'>Role</th>
                            <th style='background-color: #2F75B5;'>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='table__row'>
                            <td class='table__cell'>Rahul</td>
                            <td class='table__cell'>SoftwareEngineer</td>
                            <td class='table__cell'>55000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='table__row'>
                            <td class='table__cell'>Vinod</td>
                            <td class='table__cell'>Product Engineer</td>
                            <td class='table__cell'>66000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class='table__row'>
                            <td class='table__cell'>Amala</td>
                            <td class='table__cell'>Design Engineer</td>
                            <td class='table__cell'>43000</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                    
                </body>

                </html>
            '''
responsestring = pdfkit.from_string(html_content, False, configuration=config)

    response = make_response(responsestring)

    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'

    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=report.pdf'

    return response
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Note: I can able to generate the pdf successfully. My problem is header displayed only the first page. I want to show it's all the pages of pdf.